# Error al hacer push para servifor Bonobo con git

Tags: git

Tengo instalado el servidor Bonobo de manera local en una máquina virtual con Window 10 professional de 64 bit.

configuré el servidor y este se funciona correctamente, puedo iniciar sesión y crear usuarios.

Configuré en la arte de GIT el nombre de usuario y Email

Agregué el repositorio remoto con el siguiente comando:

```
git remote add origin http://localhost/Bonono.Git.Server/IBBAV-desarrollo.git
```

Al verificar el repositorio con `git remote -v`  me muestra esta url

```
origin https://admin@localhost/Bonono.Git.Server/IBBAV-desarrollo.git (fetch)
origin https://admin@localhost/Bonono.Git.Server/IBBAV-desarrollo.git (push)
```

Al hacer el push para el servidor con el siguiente comando `git push -u origin master`
me da el siguiente error :

> fatal: unable to acces https://localhost/Bonono.Git.Server/IBBAV-desarrollo.git: failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection Refused

Comment: He escrito una posible explicación en mi respuesta (no me cabía en un comentario). De todas formas veo una inconsistencia entre lo que te muestra `git remote -v`  (usa https) y lo que dices haber añadido con `git remote add` (usas http)

Answer (score 1):

Es extraño porque al usar `git` sobre la URL `https://localhost/Bonono.Git.Server/IBBAV-desarrollo.git`, ya que en esta URL no se especifica ningún puerto, debería conectarse al puerto 443 de localhost, que es el estándar para el protocolo HTTPS.

Se me ocurre que probablemente en ese puerto (443) esté escuchando un servidor que te redirija al puerto 1080, en el que no escucha nadie, y de ahí el error.

Puedes comprobar si es éste el caso mediante el comando:

```
curl -i https://localhost/Bonono.Git.Server/IBBAV-desarrollo.git
```

y observar la primera línea de la respuesta. Si es un código de redirección (como 301), la cabecera `Location:` te dará la URL a la que está redirigiendo (según mi hipótesis, sería `http(s)://localhost:8010`). Luego tendrías que averiguar el por qué de esa redirección. Quién está escuchando en realidad en el 443, o si es Bonobo por qué te intenta redirigir a otro puerto.